# want to show orders only to specific product owners to which orders has been given in mongodb MERN STACK DEVELOPMENT

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongodb-query, mern

This is my order  Schema
the person who actually starts the order , can get his SPECIFIC ORDERS, but the person who gets order to his product can not get specific orders.Which are his , i am copying a tutorial and making a product please help with that

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    shippingInfo: {
        address: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        city: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        phoneNo: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        postalCode: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        country: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    orderItems: [
        {
            name: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            quantity: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            },
            image: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            price: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            },
            product: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                required: true,
                ref: 'Product'
            }
        }
    ],
    paymentInfo: {
        id: {
            type: String
        },
        status: {
            type: String
        }
    },
    paidAt: {
        type: Date
    },

    itemsPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0.0
    },
    taxPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0.0
    },
    shippingPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0.0
    },
    totalPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0.0
    },
    orderStatus: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: 'Processing'
    },
    deliveredAt: {
        type: Date
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema)
```

this is my product schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter product name'],
        trim: true,
        maxLength: [100, 'Product name cannot exceed 100 characters']
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'Please enter product price'],
        maxLength: [5, 'Product name cannot exceed 5 characters'],
        default: 0.0
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter product description'],
    },
    ratings: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    images: [
        {
            public_id: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            url: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
        }
    ],
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please select category for this product'],
        enum: {
            values: [
                'Electronics',
                'Cameras',
                'Laptops',
                'Accessories',
                'Headphones',
                'Food',
                "Books",
                'Clothes/Shoes',
                'Beauty/Health',
                'Sports',
                'Outdoor',
                'Home'
            ],
            message: 'Please select correct category for product'
        }
    },
    seller: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter product seller']
    },
    stock: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'Please enter product stock'],
        maxLength: [5, 'Product name cannot exceed 5 characters'],
        default: 0
    },
    numOfReviews: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    reviews: [
        {
            user: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User',
                required: true
            },
            name: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            rating: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            },
            comment: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        }
    ],
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

these are my order controller function

```
  exports.myOrders = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
    const orders = await Order.find({ user: req.user.id })

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        orders
    })
})


// Get all orders - ADMIN  =>   /api/v1/admin/orders/
exports.allOrders = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
    const orders = await Order.find({ user: req.user.id })

    //let totalAmount = 0;

   /*  orders.forEach(order => {
        totalAmount += order.totalPrice
    })
 */
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
      //  totalAmount,
        orders
    })
})
```

the user who initiate the order can see the orders which he initiated but the person to which order was given can not get specific order
I hope i make it clear enough , please help me I am a noob

Answer (score 0):

For user you can use `Model.find({ user: user_id })`;

For seller, you should use `Model.find({ user: user_id, seller: seller_id })`

This will match orders from the USER for the SELLER

Comment: this is my order model , i want to also add the user who uploaded the product  and then filter out orders through him ?

Comment: if u want a single query then yes.